# Personalizar barra del app en Android

Tags: android, html, html5, cordova, phonegap

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en Cordova/Phonegap usando tecnologías Web. Cuando los usuarios pulsan en el botón cuadrado (*Overview*) se muestra de manera visual una serie de tarjetas con las apps abiertas, y estas tarjetas tienen una barra de color que incluye el icono, nombre y botón de cierre. Como se puede ver en esta captura:

[image: La barra de mi app 90 Seconds es gris por defecto]

A mí me interesaría que en lugar de el gris por defecto se usara un color diferente más a tono con los colores presentes en mi app, como ya hacen otras aplicaciones que tienen diferentes colores para esa barra (p.e. Chrome, azul; Email, naranja...):

[image: Ejemplo de otras apps con la barra de diferente color]

He intentado usar el meta valor [`theme-color`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android), pero no cambió nada. También probé con el [plugin status-bar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar), y aunque este sí que cambió el color de la barra de estado (*status bar*) dentro de la app, no cambió el color gris por defecto de la tarjeta en modo *overview*.

¿Se puede personalizar esa barra usando Cordova/PhoneGap? ¿Cómo se haría?

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal con phonegap se muestra sin barra del titulo, y cada programador se debe apañar en html,css y javascript, te recomiendo te mires el framework7 https://framework7.io/kitchen-sink-material/

Comment: No se como se haga en el framework que estas utilizando pero en android(nativo) se hace cambiando solo el "colorPrimary" desde el archivo de Styles, quizá esta referencia te ayude un poco. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cree un [crosspost en StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968955/customize-overview-bar-color-in-android-app-developed-with-cordova) y recibí una [respuesta de mww](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40021593/3695983) que me sirvió para resolver el problema. Ésta es una adaptación de esa respuesta.

Lo que quieres hacer se puede conseguir utilizando el plugin `headercolor`. Los pasos para usarlo serían los siguientes:

1. Instala el plugin:

   ```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-headercolor
   ```
2. En el fichero `config.xml`, añade la preferencia para el color de la barra:

   ```
   <preference name="HeaderColor" value="#becb29" />
   ```
3. (Opcional) Si quieres cambiar el color dinámicamente en tiempo de ejecución, puedes hacerlo usando el siguiente código en JavaScript:

   ```
   window.plugins.headerColor.tint("#becb29");
   ```

Aquí tienes [la documentación del plugin](https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-headercolor) (en inglés) y aquí puedes ver el resultado:

[image]